# Make function accept my Int-based value type

Tags: scala, types, value-type

Imagine the following Scala value type:

```
class Prime(val self: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(i: Int): Int = self+i
}
```

How can I make my function `inc` accept a `Prime` as its argument, but also any regular `Int`?

```
def inc(i: Int): Int = i + 1
```

Right now, I get the following type error:

```
scala> inc(new Prime(2))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Prime
 required: Int
       inc(new Prime(2))
           ^
```

I'm looking for a way to make a change either `Prime` or `inc` to allow this function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Prime` is only `int` at runtime and not at compile time, and hence you would need to have a convertor to int for it to happen.

```
implicit def backToInt(p:Prime): Int = p.self
```

And now you can pass `inc(new Prime(2))` which would be implicitly converted to int. However this defeats the point of value types, which is type-safety.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to extend this to the use of `Int` in type arguments? I.e. to make it work with this as well: `def sum(is: Iterable[Int]) = is.fold(0)(_ + _)` ... `sum(Seq(new Prime(2), new Prime(3)))`

Comment: I want to save myself the effort of typing that extra transformation, as it distracts from the actual logic

Comment: Why do you want `Prime` in the first place then?